# Sitecore content editor running js and iframes

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

When using the content editor in Sitecore, we are noticing that if someone is editing an 'open html' field or something similar, the javascript and iframes are getting executed on the content editor page.

This isn't the behavior I would expect within the content editor. Is there a setting or pipeline I can edit to prevent this?

As an example, if I insert  alert('foo')  into a rich text field.  When I load the content editor, I get an alert saying 'foo'.

Comment: What is the exact version of Sitecore are you running?

Comment: This is the way the Telerik RadEditor is set up, I have no idea if you can disable it or not. I presume you have disabled `HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14173877/661447 I would suggest you put the JavaScript in a Multi-Line Text field.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the content editor shows the rendered HTML rather than the raw source - just think: if you edited your field with paragraph tags and headings etc you'd want to see the final output, not the raw HTML.

If you select the 'View' tab in the content editor then check 'Raw Values' you can see the raw HTML rather than the final output.

In your case I would suggest using a different field type such as `Multi-Line Text`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some differences depend on the Sitecore version and if you use webforms or MVC. If you want to change the behavior a custom Field Renderer for webforms is an option.

See [Multi / Single line Text with HTML in Sitecore](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/single-line-text-with-html.aspx) this is for Multi / Single line Text Fields but for rich text it should the same.